# How to get Top 1 with Sort from Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Instead of doing something like this:

```
SELECT
 t1.*,
 (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Name FROM Table2 t2 Order By t2.Number) Val1
FROM Table1 t1
```

How would it be done with a Join instead?

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  TOP 1 t2.Name 
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 Order By t2.Number
```

or is it even possible?

Comment: You can not do top 1 for some of table column while join. You can get top 1 record for all select statement.

Comment: Is there a join field between two tables or not

Comment: @EidMorsy yes there is

Comment: Your example will take the first row (according to `t2.Number`) without looking for a join field... Is there a `WHERE` too?

Comment: What does the documentation say about using TOP?

Comment: Why do you want this? If you need one single column (=a *scalar value*) from `Table2` this approach is fine. If you need more columns, you can use an `APPLY` like `OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM ... WHERE ...) AS ...` or a `JOIN` to a *sub-select* like `LFET JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM ... WHERE ...) AS ... ON ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  top 1 * from (SELECT t1.*, t2.Number num FROM table1 t1  JOIN table2 t2 on t1.commoncolumn=t2.commoncolumn ) t order by t.num
```

Comment: I think, the OP did not want to get only 1 record back, but to join with one special row, which is the max or min to a given sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (id is the join field)

```
with Table2Data as
 (
  SELECT Id , Name ,row_number() over(partition by Id order by number) rowNumber FROM Table2 
 )
 select t1.* ,t2.name from table1 t1 
 inner join Table2Data t2 on t1.Id=t2.Id and t2.rowNumber=1
```

Comment: You want to number **all rows** just get the first in a group?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a `CROSS APPLY`. Assuming `Id` is the common field:

```
SELECT t1.*
  , t3.Name
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 t2.Name
  FROM Table2 t2
  WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id
  ORDER BY t2.Number
) t3
```

Answer (score 0):

The following accomplishes the same thing.

```
SELECT t1.*, MIN(t2.Name) OVER() val1 FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```